# How Can I Get A Substring From A Long Text Area Field?

Tags: soql, formula-field, substring

I have a Description field of type Long Text Area. I'm trying to get the first few lines to display. 
1. I tried creating a formula field

```
LEFT(Description, 500)
```

I get Error: You referenced an unsupported field type called "Long Text Area" using the following field: Description. 
2.I tried using SOQL but I couldn't get it to work. 
3.I also tried something like

```
 <apex:outputText value="{!LEFT(GoodMorning,4)}"/>
```

I got the following error : Failed to save HighlightComponent.cmp: c:HighlightComponent:26,75: No function found for key: LEFT: Source

How can I get a substring of the description field to show up in a custom lightning component. Here's my code:

Controller

```
public class HighlightComponentController {
@AuraEnabled        

    public static List<Case> findCase (Id recordId) {
        List<Case> details = [SELECT CaseNumber, OwnerId, Description 
                             FROM Case WHERE Id=:recordId];

        return details;
    }

    String description { get; private set; }

    public String truncatedDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return (description == null) ? null : description.abbreviate(3);
        }
    }

}
```

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="truncatedDescription" type="String" />
  <p><lightning:formattedText value="{!v.truncatedDescription}"/></p>
```

Javascript

```
{
  doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.findCase");
    action.setParams({
        recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set("v.details", data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    var action2 = component.get("c.truncatedDescription");

    action2.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        component.set("v.truncatedDescription", data.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action2);
}
```

Comment: If you can use SOQL, why not make use of [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).substring(startIndex, endIndex)?

Comment: I didn't think SOQL had a substring method. Here's what my code looks like public static List<Case> findCase (Id recordId) {
        List<Case> details = [SELECT CaseNumber, OwnerId, Description FROM Case WHERE Id=:recordId];
        
        return details;

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. Do not drop code in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference Long Text Area fields in formulas of any type. You will have to use Apex.

For example, if you have a controller already, set a `truncatedDescription` instead of just `Description`.

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public String description { get; private set; }
    public String truncatedDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return (description == null) ? null : description.abbreviate(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help here's what I have in the controller so far

Comment: @LauraBejjani So just reference `truncatedDescription` instead of `description` where you want the shorter version.

Comment: Thanks for your help here's what I have in the controller so far  public static List<Case> findCase (Id recordId) { List<Case> details = [SELECT CaseNumber, OwnerId, Description FROM Case WHERE Id=:recordId]; return details; How would I do what you describe and display it. I currently have   <lightning:formattedText value="{!item.Description}"/>

Comment: @LauraBejjani Please stop dumping code in the comments. Rather, add it to your question via an **edit**.

Comment: I have updated my question. I'm new to Salesforce Development and I'm not sure how to get this to display in my component. I'm currently getting an empty field.

Comment: Hi @Adrian Larson - I have updated the code in my question. I'm new to Salesforce Development and I'm not sure how to get this to display in my component. I'm currently getting an empty field.